# How to extract names via regex from strings of name = value format

Tags: c, regex, string, pcre

How to extract names via regex from strings of name = value format?
I want to get from strings

```
saf asfgo   = ==slwin[(*]?
m||a=vd8228J)_+
sPiof+_ = vsfs=+":~lue3
```

only names:

```
saf asfgo
m||a
sPiof+_
```

wihout first equals sign and whitespace preceding it.

upd. I tried to use `^.+(?=[ \t]*?=)`
upd2. Sorry. I quickly found decision: `^.+?(?=[ \t]*=)`

Comment: What is the language? Can you tag it?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
if ($subject =~ m/(?im)^([^=\r\n]+?)\s*=\s*([^=\r\n]+?)$/) {
    $name = $1;
    $value = $2;
} else {
    $name = "";
    $value = "";
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is great. Groups are what i needed. Now i can get trimmed name and trimmed value ^(.+?)[ \t]*=[ \t]*(.+?$). Thanks.